# Not able to modify onChange of react-timezone-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone, react-select

I am using the [react-timezone-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timezone-select) npm package. The below code is given in its Usage example source code. How can I modify its onChange function so that I can write console.log print statements inside its onChange method

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TimezoneSelect from 'react-timezone-select'

const App = () => {
  const [selectedTimezone, setSelectedTimezone] = useState({})

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h2>react-timezone-select</h2>
      <blockquote>Please make a selection</blockquote>
      <div className='select-wrapper'>
        <TimezoneSelect
          value={selectedTimezone}
          onChange={setSelectedTimezone}
        />
      </div>
      <h3>Output:</h3>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#ccc',
          padding: '20px',
          margin: '20px auto',
          borderRadius: '5px',
          maxWidth: '600px',
        }}
      >
        <pre
          style={{
            margin: '0 20px',
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: 'monospace',
          }}
        >
          {JSON.stringify(selectedTimezone, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

I tried modifying the `onChange` method to the following, but that disrupts the functionality of the select component in react

```
 onChange={() => {
 setSelectedTimezone(selectedTimezone);
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to `console.log(selectedTimezone)` before return?
selectedTimezone is changing whenever we change something in `TimezoneSelect` component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using react-timezone-select, you can create a dropdown as I did below. This way, the offset is updated when the daylight setting is on and you can still have valid data. I used moment timezone to get latest offset against a timezone.

```
export const TIMEZONE_OPTIONS = [
{ label: 'Niue', tzCode: 'Pacific/Niue' },
{ label: 'Pago Pago', tzCode: 'Pacific/Pago_Pago' },
{ label: 'Palmer', tzCode: 'Antarctica/Palmer' },
{ label: 'Kiritimati', tzCode: 'Pacific/Kiritimati' },
].map(tz => {
 const offset = moment.tz(tz.tzCode).format('Z');
return {
key: tz.tzCode,
value: `(GMT${offset}) ${tz.label}`,
};
});
```

[image: Dropdown Output]